# part of the image

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

using the canvas tag in HTML5, you can load a small area of ​​a large image? and have very low load times?
Why would I want to make a play, with a few tiles but rather large, so you have a few loops (for).
I'd like to redraw only a specific area when you animate a character for example, minimizing the time.

Answer (score 2):

context.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight)

**s** = source, **d** = destination.

[image]

source https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images#drawImage_example_3

But you cannot improve load time you will have to load it before you can crop it !

Good luck